# Carrierwave path to versioned file in uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I need to convert uploaded video files with carrierwave. Uploader:

```
class MediaItemUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  version :video_for_device, if: :video? do
    process :encode_video_for_device 
  end

  storage :file

  private

    def video? file
      if file.path.ends_with?('avi') || ...
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end

    def encode_video_for_device
      input_file = file.path
      output_file = # How to get the output file path?
      system("ffmpeg -i #{input_file} -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict -2 #{output_file}")
    end
end
```

But how do I get the output file path and tell carrierwave to attach this file?
If I hardcode `output_file` then ffmpeg works fine, but carrierwave puts same file named 'video_for_device_#{original_filename}' along with original file. But I need to process this new file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
def encode_video_for_device
  tmp_path = File.join File.dirname(current_path), "#{SecureRandom.hex}.mp4"
  system("ffmpeg -i #{current_path} -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict -2 #{tmp_path}")
  File.rename tmp_path, current_path
end
```

`current_path` is a path of the current file which has to be modified before attaching.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta return the processed file in the end of the method, so this should do it:

```
def encode_video_for_device
  input_file = file.path
  output_file = "/whatever/temp/filename"
  system("ffmpeg -i #{input_file} -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict -2 #{output_file}")
  File.new(output_file)
end
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. Carrierwave creates file named `video_for_device_...` along with original file which is a copy of the original.